# How can I make a windows to be "always on top" in Motif mwm?

Tags: x11, window-manager, motif

An old-school UNIX question:

Motif allows to have a X11 motif MWM window always on top by code.

However, I would like to know if I can make the same with an external command (in a similar way you can change the name of an existing window with `xdotool`)

Comment: What does "window on top by code" mean? Can you give a concrete example to make your question more clear, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The X11 window will stay always above any other window, no matter if it has the focus or if you move around other windows over this one